# How to adjust two correlated values

Tags: r, time, regression, normalization, correlation

I'm trying to understand the magnitude of change a certain event had on the performance of a button.

I have a data frame like so: **Date, Image Renders, and Image Clicks.**

I calculate a year over year percent of renders and clicks to understand the annual growth. I know that renders and clicks are correlated because render is the previous step to a click. I track these two values on a daily level and my final table looks like the following:

```
Day, render, click
1, -10%, 3%
2, 3%, 7%
3, -2%, 5%
...
```

How do I find the % growth of click per day if the render was adjusted to 0. One day I tried was find the correlation between render and click, and scale each day. Render to click correlation is `50%;` therefore, on day 1 if you increase render by 10% the click percent will end up being `8%` because

```
10% * .5 + 3% = 8%
```

I have a feeling there is a better way to do this so I'm asking for help. I do my calculation in R so would be helpful if someone knew how to do this in R. Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide a `dput(head(df))` of your data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a model, in which you then plug your values of render to get the predicted click

```
m <- lm(click ~ render)
summary(m)
coef(m) # gets the coefs so you can plug values in
```